# How can I create a Honeycomb network topology by representing a graph as an adjacency list

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

Given N nodes, I want to build a graph of honeycomb network out of it. It can be a complete one like an SMn where number of nodes is given by 6n^2 or can have more than a strict SMn, say 50 nodes, which has 26 nodes more than an SM2. Goal is to build an adjacency list where each node can have a maximum degree of 3.

Given 50 nodes to create a honeycomb network out of, I pick the first 6 nodes from a queue and treat it as a bipartite graph. N1, N3 and N5 are black nodes, N2, N4 and N6 are white. Build the initial adjacency list creating a cycle N1->N2->N3->N4->N5->N6 ->N1, call it layer 1 nodes.

There is room to add 6 new nodes, one to each vertex of the hexagon, so I get 6 more nodes from the queue, 3 black and 3 white and connect the opposites and call them layer 2. Similarly, go on until I have exhausted all the nodes and update the adjacency list. Need some help on how I could improve this algorithm or any suggestions on how I can implement this would be great![enter image description here][1]

Comment: `Similarly, go on until I have exhausted all the nodes ` - can you?   Looks to me like when you complete level 2 then all 12 nodes each have 3 adjacent nodes, so no more nodes can be added.

Comment: The outermost nodes just have a degree of 2. I was taking SM2 as an example, but my goal is to continue till I have exhausted all the nodes in the given input. I hope the below link helps. Nodes N13, N14, N15 have a degree of 2 once I complete the SM2, and are still good to connect to one more node as I have shown in the diagram.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12aZKkRl4tj-0xvpNWebECZFCLg7YiEu2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah - my mistake, thanks for the diagram :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constructing the graph, there are a couple of different options to consider alongside the procedure you have described :

1) Imagine a little robot tracing a continuous line.  So it starts with N1->N2->N3->N4->N5->N6.
Then when going to N1 realises that it has hit this point already, so moves out in its continuous line N1->N8, and then continues :

- N8->N15->N16->N9 (and also connects to N2)
- N9->N18->N17->N10 (and also connects to N3)
- ......
- ....N24->N7 (and also connects to N6)
- N7->N14->N13->N8 - where it realises that the node it should "also connect to" is one that it's already done (ie it's back where it started for this level), so moves back to N13 and creates the node for the next level out and then continues from there.

So this will require a bit of smarts to know which node to "also connect to", etc, but it must follow a regular general pattern and so be straightforward to implement/maintain.

Option 2) Both approaches (yours, and my option (1)) are great for an initial setup according to a fixed pattern, but what if you also need (now or in the future) at add new nodes on demand ?   eg, suppose you have a requirement to allow a graph to be built up by dropping nodes in a sequence (but always connecting to at least one pre-existing) : N1, N2, N6, N5, N8, N15, N16, N9

Let's consider that last one, adding N9 to N16.  Looking at the graph, we can immediately see that it must also connect to N2 - but how can we program that ?   There are two options (again !! ) :

Option 2a) When adding each node (such as N9 to N16), we recursively traverse the entire tree, accumulating offsets (how far up/down and left/right from N9 we are) until we find a matching node.   IMHO, complex and timeconsuming

Option 2b) Once each node has been placed, it can calculate its coordinates in the graph from that of the node it is attached to - eg, our sequence becomes :

N1(0,0) , N2(1,0) , N6(-1,-1),  N5(0,-2), N8(-1,1), N15(0,2), N16(1,2), N9(2,1)

So now, when adding node N9, we can obviously calculate the coordinates of any nodes that it should be attached to - (1,0) and (3,1) - and so simply iterate straight across the list looking for any existing nodes at those coordinates (and thus immediately finding N2).   Coordinates could also be handy for other uses (displaying, etc).